# vuex mapstate shows only the latest new value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a mapstate which i am using to map vuex store changes for a particular module.following is the code for the same.

```
             computed: mapState('myStore1', {
                newMessageReceived: state => state['newmessage'],
              }),

              watch: {
                newMessageReceived(newVal, oldValue) {
                  //newValue and oldValue are populated
                }
              }
```

Somewhere in other components i push some messages:

```
              const message1 = "Object 1 here"
              const message2 = "Object 2 here"
              const message3 = "Object 3 here"

              this.$store.dispatch('myStore1/setNewMessage', message1);
              this.$store.dispatch('myStore1/setNewMessage', message2);
              this.$store.dispatch('myStore1/setNewMessage', message3);
```

In mutations.ts file the set method gets called three times.

```
               const mutations = {
                  SET_NEW_MESSAGE(state, payload) {
                    const newPayload = Object.assign({}, payload);
                    state.newMessage = newPayload;
                  },
                };
                export { mutations };
```

But i always receive the third object back in my component where i have mapState used to consume. Not sure what is causing the issue here.

Comment: Isn't it expected the third object will override the first two ?

Comment: If i have the messages coming from three different components. They work. I was expecting each state change will trigger a watch change. It only notifies me about the last message in this case where all three are one after another.